# Differences between the cheap and expensive CAT6 keystone jacks

Tags: cat6

There are keystone jacks that I can purchase for $15AUD, and others for $4. Both advertise CAT6 support.

This isn't a 5e vs 6 discussion, purely the advertised price of two CAT6 keystones. Are there measurable differences between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences between the two jacks are mainly in their relative build quality. They will likely perform exactly the same, however the more expensive one will stand up to more abuse before breaking.